# Can one deduce what is the kernel of homomorphism from info on orders of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I got this question, and it seems some information is missing.

Let $G,H$ be groups, gcd$(|G|,|H|)=1$. Let $f:G \rightarrow H$ be homomorphism. What's $ker(f)$?

So I reached so far to the conclusion that gcd$(|ker(f)|,|H|)=1$ and gcd$(|ker(f)|,|im(f)|)=1$. Don't have an idea about how proceeding. Is it using the fact that $ker(f)$ is normal?

Hints would be appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two finite groups and you know $|ker\left(f\right)||im\left(f\right)|=|G|$, that $im\left(f\right)$ is a subgroup of $H$ and hence $|im\left(f\right)|$ divides $|H|$. So $|im\left(f\right)|$ divides both $|H|$ and $|G|$, so it has to be $1$. So you get that the homomorphism is zero.

Comment: We haven't studied that $|ker(f)||im(f)|=|G|$ yet. Is there another way?

Comment: You can see $|ker||im|=G$ this way: you know that ker is a subgroup, hence $|ker|$ divides $|G|$. Then you know that $G/ker \cong im$. Hence you know that the number of cosets w.r.t. $ker$ are $|im|$. You know that any coset w.r.t. ker has cardinality $|ker|$ and that they are a partition of $G$. So you have $|im|$ subsets, each one with cardinality $|ker|$, whose disjointed union is $G$. Then you get what I used. Note I am using $G$ finite.

Comment: but i'm unclear of why you concluded that since $G/ker$ isomorphic to $im$, the number of cosets w.r.t. $ker$ are $|im|$

Comment: Because the group $G/ker$ is the group whose elements are the cosets of $G$ w.r.t. $ker$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $ \frac{G}{Ker(f)} \cong  f(G) \leq H$